# Is it possible to add a bitmap into BitmapMemoryCache manually in Fresco?

Tags: android, caching, fresco

I need to manually add a bitmap to the cache specifying the URI (as key). If the request URI to download the image matches with the key, I need the pipeline to load the bitmap from the cache instead of making the network call.

I found this method `Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getBitmapMemoryCache().cache( cacheKey, closeableReference)`. But how to get a closableReference to an arbitrary bitmap. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading image with Fresco - yes:

```
public class OperationPostprocessor extends BasePostprocessor {
  private int myParameter;

  public OperationPostprocessor(int param) {
    myParameter = param;
  }

  public void process(Bitmap bitmap) { 
    doSomething(myParameter);
  }

  public CacheKey getPostprocessorCacheKey() {
    return new MyCacheKey(myParameter);
  }
}
```

Cache key is **MyCacheKey(myParameter)**

You can use it when you are forming ImageRequest:

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(photoUri)
                .setPostprocessor(new OperationPostprocessor())
                .build();
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setOldController(simpleDraweeView.getController())
                .setImageRequest(request)
                .build();
simpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

Here you will use your postprocessor: **.setPostprocessor(new OperationPostprocessor())**

---

Resources:

- http://frescolib.org/docs/modifying-image.html
- http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html

---

**One detail**: here will be using fresco cache, but in *Postprocessor.process(Bitmap)* method, i think, you can add bitmap to your own cache.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post explaining observations / experience with Fresco [here](http://coolwebscripts.blogspot.in/2016/04/my-experience-with-using-fresco-android.html).

Also check this post at [medium](https://medium.com/@chethann123/my-experience-using-fresco-b45cc36ac878#.56vnkv4e3)

It has the solution to above problem too.